# JQuery Ui tabs pagination deprecated

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using UI Tabs Paging extension - v1.2.2 in legacy system. 
https://code.google.com/archive/p/jquery-ui-tabs-paging/

It supports jQuery 1.9.0 and jQuery UI 1.9.0 . I need to upgrade to support latest version of Jquery and Jquery UI as deprecated message appears on third party customer security testing.

Is it any other option or alternatives ? I search but could not able to identify the best solution.

Comment: I suspect you would need to find the deprecated elements in the plugin and modernize them. Otherwise I would consider using a more modern plugin that is still supported.

Comment: Actually ui.tabs.paging.js contains the comments with for jQuery 1.9.0 and jQuery UI 1.9.0) . We can't remove this comments from the file right due to copyrights ? Can we ? 
Can you let me know the more modern plugins ? I hadn't find out . Everyone using jquery ui tabs pagination.

Comment: "*Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions: The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.*"

Comment: Do you also mean this plugin: https://github.com/Akshay-Hegde/jquery-ui-tabs-paging ?

Comment: Yes . I am using this plugins .

Comment: Actually i checked this plugins with jquery v1.10.2 and its perfectly working with it. Customer security test search the copyright and find out that this plugins deprecated . So can we remove the Jquery version support info comments from copyright?

Comment: I cannot tell you how to do your job. That is up to you and your company.

Answer (score 0):

Testing here with jQuery 3.3.1 & jQuery UI 1.12.1: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ry2gyhee/ I do not see an issue with the code. There are some area where it can be updated and improved.

My Test are based on the example provided at https://github.com/Akshay-Hegde/jquery-ui-tabs-paging/blob/wiki/ProjectHome.md

**HTML**

```
<div id="example">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab4">Tab 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab5">Tab 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab6">Tab 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab7">Tab 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab8">Tab 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab9">Tab 9</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab10">Tab 10</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab11">Tab 11</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab12">Tab 12</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab13">Tab 13</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab14">Tab 14</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab15">Tab 15</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tab1">Tab 1</div>
  <div id="tab2">Tab 2</div>
  <div id="tab3">Tab 3</div>
  <div id="tab4">Tab 4</div>
  <div id="tab5">Tab 5</div>
  <div id="tab6">Tab 6</div>
  <div id="tab7">Tab 7</div>
  <div id="tab8">Tab 8</div>
  <div id="tab9">Tab 9</div>
  <div id="tab10">Tab 10</div>
  <div id="tab11">Tab 11</div>
  <div id="tab12">Tab 12</div>
  <div id="tab13">Tab 13</div>
  <div id="tab14">Tab 14</div>
  <div id="tab15">Tab 15</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $('#example').tabs();
  $('#example').tabs('paging', {
    cycle: true,
    follow: true
  });
});
```

Based on these tests, I would say it's fully functional. If you do not agree, please update your post with a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Would consider using the jQuery UI Widget Factory to leverage it's abilities and make improvements.

Comment: Its working in my end also with updated jquery version. Only problems is  the copyright. Can we able to update the copyright to add support of Jquery 1.10 or  above ?

Comment: I can't update copyright . If you have any alternative let me know

Comment: @Mahesh I do not and I am unable to identify this security test. So I cannot assist.